# Phpmyadmin version cli

Tags: bash, programming, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin from this tutorial:
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-debian/
I would like to check the version using a terminal, but the command doesn't work. I mean "phpmyadmin --version, phpmyadmin -version"
I need a with terminal version checking because I need this for a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `cat` and `jq` (operates on JSON files) commands to find phpmyadmin version from the `package.json` file located in the root directory.

This example assumes that phpmyadmin is extracted to `/home/user/phpmyadmin/`.

```
$ cd /home/user/phpmyadmin
$ cat package.json | jq .version
"5.2.0"
```

`cat` should already be installed so just install `jq` using `apt`:

```
apt install jq
```

> jq - Command-line JSON processor